# Connecting two Hilbert spaces' inner products via isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If I have two Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a continuous linear isomorphism $T:X \to Y$ with continuous inverse $T^{-1}:Y\to X$, is there anyway to write
$$(a,b)_X$$ as an inner product on $Y$?

I know I can do this if $T$ is an isometric isomorphism, but if it's not, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pullback $(T^{-1})^\ast(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ of $(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ from $X$ to $Y$ via $T^{-1}$, defined by
$$(T^{-1})^\ast(\eta,\xi)_X := (T^{-1}\eta,T^{-1}\xi)_X, \quad \eta,\xi \in Y,$$
will be *some* inner product on the vector space $Y$ inducing a norm equivalent to the original Hilbert space norm on $Y$, whether or not $T$ is isometric. In particular, then, $(T^{-1})^\ast(\cdot,\cdot)_X = (\cdot,\cdot)_Y$ if and only if $T^{-1}$ is an isometry, if and only if $T$ is an isometry.

EDIT: In particular, 
$$(T^{-1})^\ast(\eta,\xi)_X := (T^{-1}\eta,T^{-1}\xi)_X = (\eta,(T T^\ast)^{-1}\xi)_Y, \quad \eta,\xi \in Y,$$
so that understanding $(T^{-1})^\ast(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ is the same as understanding the operator $TT^\ast$ on $Y$ and its inverse $(TT^\ast)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. But one can't write down a formula for the inner product on $Y$ explicitly, I guess :(

Comment: @george.s See the edit for the most that can be said _a priori_. Basically, the best you can do, given what you have, is to compare $(T^{-1})^\ast(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ with $(\cdot,\cdot)_Y$ as inner products on $Y$, and by the edit, understanding $(T^{-1})^\ast(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ in terms of $(\cdot,\cdot)_Y$ is equivalent to understanding the operator $(TT^\ast)^{-1}$ on $Y$ with $(\cdot,\cdot)_Y$.